# Android - Should Navigation Drawer Activity be Home Screen in Android Applications?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation

I am learning Navigation Drawer. In most of the examples given on internet, fragments are used.

**My requirement is:**

1. Home activity should contain Navingation Drawer
2. When I click on any item in the navigation drawer, a new activity should get opened with the BACK arrow (<--)
3. When I click on the BACK arrow, again I come to the Home screen with Navigation Drawer

If I look into most of the applications installed on my mobile like PayTM, all are operating like this.

**My Approach**

I am adding a Navigation Drawer Activity and making it the MAIN activity in the Manifest file like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".NavigationDrawerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_navigation_drawer"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Adding BACK button in all other activities which open from the menu items of this drawer like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_class);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

**Question:** Should I make Navigation Drawer Activity as Home Screen and call other activities from here (By clicking on menu items on the navigation drawer)? Is this the right approach? Do other applications also use this approach which use Navigation Drawer? If this is not the best approach, then how should I implement my requirement? Do I need fragments as mentioned in almost all the tutorials of Navigation Drawer?

Thanks!

Comment: You may wish to ask your question here http://ux.stackexchange.com and read post like http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74934/android-ux-when-to-use-tabs-and-when-to-use-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common NavigationDrawer Across All Activity Example is here
 refer below Link for that

[Common NavigationDrawer](https://github.com/Rishisahu/BaseActivityConcept)

this is Example of open Activity from NavigationDrawer and if u extend BaseActivity than NavigationDrawer will implement on that activity and where u do not want navigation drawer, do not extend BaseActivity